# How to capture DOM animations as lossless 60fps video with code only approach

Tags: javascript, animation, dom, automation, video-capture

This is a hard problem from the research I have done so thanks in advance for taking some time to look into it cause I'm totally stuck!

I need a way to capture DOM animations in 60fps lossless video and do it in a way that can be automated and integrated into an app so that I can capture hundreds of variations of a single animation as video.

**How it might work:**

`capture-video https://codepen.io/RobinTreur/full/pyWLeB/ --length 10s --size 800x600`

Script would visit that url (contains a text animation example) and then output a video that shows the captured animation as a 60fps video without lagging.

**Requirements:**

- Must be a code-based or automation friendly approach.
- Must record high quality 60fps video of DOM animations without lag.
- Must record basic DOM element animations, not canvas or WebGL based.

Thank you so much for your help! This has been a very hard problem to solve. I would love to give back somehow to whoever solves this problem.

If you have any questions just comment and I will respond same day. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get full script here at StackOverflow. But, I can give you steps to write your own script.

Please note following step works only in linux.

Pre-requisites:

1. `Xvfb`
2. `ffmpeg`
3. `google chrome`

Steps:

1. Launch `google chrome` in `Xvfb`

   ```
   xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0, 1024x768x16' google-chrome -start-maximized http://www.example.com > /dev/null &
   ```

   In above command `-screen` is display number that need to be changed with each instance your run. `Xvfb` will launch a virtual screen and give it that number. After launching screen, it will open google chrome in it.
2. Launch `ffmpeg` and give it a display number give aboven along with any offset to align capturing window.

   ```
   ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 60 -f x11grab -i :0.0+100,200 output.mp4
   ```

   In above command `:0` is display number that need to be adjusted as per instance. Note that if you want to capture upto `10s` then it can be adjusted by passing `-t` flag in ffmpeg.

*Note: Once done, remember to dispose `Xvfb` screen and any other dangling process.*

Comment: Thanks this looks like an interesting approach I will try this later today and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried to use ffmpeg to record chrome in xvfb like this. My problem is when play video in chrome and record it by ffmpeg, I see lag after few second. The image stop for a while then run again. Not sure it's because of chrome or ffmpeg. Any thought ?

Comment: This mainly occurs when ffmpeg use most of your resources (ram/cpu). Try increasing your resources.

Comment: When running ffmpeg command, getting error, Cannot open display :0.0+100,200, error 1.
:0.0+100,200: Input/output error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into Puppeteer or Selenium.
I know they can take screenshots, so maybe they will be able to record sufficient video as well.

I found [this](https://github.com/clipisode/puppeteer-recorder#readme) library which seems to do exactly what you ask for. I haven't used it though, so I can't vouch for it.